# How many heroes I can play for free when I buy Heroes of the Storm Founder's Pack?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

It is written [here](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/01/21/heroes-of-the-storm-founders-pack-now-available) that "Anyone who opts to buy a Founder's Pack will get access to Raynor, Diablo and Tyrande for use as heroes". But 3 heroes sounds like not a lot of fun and I know that during Alpha people could get access to all heroes using so called "rotation pull" (accessible heroes where different each week).
So, is it true that buying the Founder's Pack I can play with 3 heroes only unless I spend money, or I can unlock some other heroes too?

**How many heros I can play if I buy Heroes of the Storm Founder's Pack**, if I don't want to use extra real money?

Comment: It's also worth noting that -all- heroes can be bought with in-game gold, which you earn by playing Coop/Quick Match/Hero League games. It is a slow grind, but the main benefit of that pack truly is the beta access and skin unlocks.

Comment: @MikeR, that's not true. Tyrande and Diablo costs 7000 each.

Comment: @klm123 Sorry I was wrong about the hero prices.  I've deleted my comment

Comment: Note that Hero League, the "Ranked Games" of HotS, is only available after you purchased 10 Heroes. These 10 Heroes **do not** include the heroes that are currently in the weekly rotation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will always get access to those 3 heroes regardless of what is on rotation for the week. You get a total of 10 heroes to choose from  when you reach account level 15 (you will start with 6 in the rotation). If those 3 are not in the rotation then you will get access to 13 heroes to pick from for that week. If any number of them are part of the rotation then your total number will drop by that number. For example, if Diablo was part of the rotation for the week you would have access to 12 heroes.

On the flip side, if all 3 are in rotation that week then you only have the 10 to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

All heroes can be bought with in-game gold as well as real world money. In-game gold is earned by playing, so you can play all heroes without spending any real world money. The only items which require you to spend real world money to get them are cosmetic items.

If you don't own any heroes, you can only play the 5 heroes on the weekly rotation, which are the same for everyone and change Tuesday morning. If you level up you to level 15 (which takes about 10-15 hours) you will be able to play 7 different heroes on the weekly rotation.

Owning a hero allows you to play that hero when it isn't on the weekly rotation. Heroes cost 2'000, 4'000, 7'000, or 10'000 in-game gold, depending on the hero. 
Related: [How do you earn Gold in Heroes of the Storm?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231171/how-do-you-earn-gold-in-heroes-of-the-storm/231174#231174)